# Set up docker file to clone a laravel github project

Tags: laravel, git, docker, dockerfile, clone

I am new in laravel and docker. I have a laravel repository and want to clone it and set up docker for it. How to setup docker file for it and what should i write in docker file?

Comment: https://appdividend.com/2018/04/12/how-to-setup-laravel-in-docker-container/ will help you

Answer (score 2):

Beside using [laradock](http://laradock.io/), a more step-by-step approach is described in "[Laravel in Docker](https://buddy.works/guides/laravel-in-docker)" and the example repository [`buddy-works/laravel-first-steps`](https://github.com/buddy-works/laravel-first-steps).

It uses as an example Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

Comment: Thanks alot  for dockerfile.